# How do I prepare a ceiling for restomping?

Tags: repair, drywall, ceiling, patching-drywall, mudding

I had to cut access panels in the ceiling of a 7' x 11' room to make several plumbing repairs.  The ceiling has the slapbrush/stomp texture:

[image]

I have patched the drywall and I plan on restomping the whole ceiling as opposed to trying to match a patch.  After knocking off the brittle tips with a knife, can I simply roll on another coat of mud and stomp?  The patches I made are smooth.  Do I need to wet the ceiling down and knock it down with a knife or a sponge before I restomp to get the best results and hide the patches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would dampen the areas you patched, any areas that were/are painted won't absorb enough to matter.

If you are thinning premixed joint compound you should be able to roll it on and stomp. Cool pattern.

Comment: I just bought a brush at lunch to do this, but now I am wondering if I have the right one.  How do I know which brush type did this design?

Comment: Lol, I was going to ask what brush you'd used.. Time for a new question..  Some experimenting is in order.  There are a LOT of designers over at houzz.com, post a pic there.

Comment: I think people call the design Rosebud. I don't think stomping a ceiling would be difficult, but it is in eyeshot of another ceiling, so I may get someone who knows what they are doing to try and match it.

Comment: Another way might be to skim coat the whole room and use a different pattern..

Comment: I just rolled on the mud as thick as I could and stomped it all.  You can see the patched areas as the other areas have both patterns but it is pretty good.  I think knocking it all down while moist would have helped hide the patches if I ever have to do it again.